# What does "Changing Skies" do?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

FFXIII-2's final boss has an ability called "Changing Skies".

... It literally changes the sky. Well, aside from that, what else is this ability supposed to do? I don't see how it is affecting me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing Skies is cast by Jet Bahamut.

This buffs the other 2 Bahamuts (Garnet and Amber) with haste as well as Bravery for Garnet and Faith for Amber.